# Custom Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a set of stream stages (Sources, Flows and Sinks) which I would like to add some MetaData information to.

Therefore rather than Sources producing A -> (A, StreamMetaData). I've managed to do this using custom stream stages whereby on grab(in) the element, I push(out, (elem, StreamMetaData)). In reality it is not 'converting' the existing Source but passing it to a flow to recreate a new source.

Now I'm trying to implement the below MetaStream stage:

[image: 1]

Therefore given that the source is producing tuples of (A, StreamMetaData), I want to pass the A to an existing Flow for some computation to take place and then merge the output produced 'B' with the StreamMetaData. These will then be passed to a Sink which accepts (B, StreamMetaData).

How would you suggest I go about it. I've been informed partial graphs are the best bet and would help in completing such a task. UniformFanOut and UniformFanIn using Unzip((A streamMetaData), A, StreamMetaData) and Zip(A,B)

```
 val fanOut = GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
    val unzip = b.add(Unzip[T, StreamMetaData]) 
    UniformFanOutShape(unzip.in, unzip.out0, unzip.out1)
  }

  val fanIn = GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
    val zip = b.add(Zip[T ,StreamMetaData]()) 
    UniformFanInShape(zip)
  }
```

How can I connect the fanIn and fanOut so as to achieve the same behavior as in the picture?

I had something like this in mind;

```
 def metaFlow[T, B, Mat](flow: Flow[T, B, Mat]): Unit = {
   val wrappedFlow =
     Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(){ implicit b =>
       import GraphDSL.Implicits._

       val unzip: FanOutShape2[(T, StreamMetaData), T, StreamMetaData] = b.add(Unzip[T, StreamMetaData])
       val existingFlow = b.add(flow)
       val zip: FanInShape2[B,StreamMetaData,(B,StreamMetaData)] = b.add(Zip[B, StreamMetaData])

       unzip.out0 ~> existingFlow ~> zip.in0
       unzip.out1 ~> zip.in1

       FlowShape(unzip.in, zip.out)
     })

 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This aprox creating a new SourceShape stacking flow graph can work, a little bit different of your flowShape implementation.

```
  def sourceGraph[A, B](f: A => B, source: Source[(A, StreamMetaData), NotUsed]) = Source.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val unzip = builder.add(Unzip[A, StreamMetaData]())
    val zip   = builder.add(Zip[B, StreamMetaData]())

    val flow0  = builder.add(Flow[A].map { f(_) })

    val flow1 = source ~> unzip.in
                          unzip.out0 ~> flow0 ~> zip.in0
                          unzip.out1          ~> zip.in1


    SourceShape(zip.out)
  })



def flowGraph[A, B](f: A => B) = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val unzip = builder.add(Unzip[A, StreamMetaData]())
    val zip   = builder.add(Zip[B, StreamMetaData]())

    val flow0  = builder.add(Flow[A].map { f(_) })

    unzip.out0 ~> flow0 ~> zip.in0
    unzip.out1          ~> zip.in1

    FlowShape(unzip.in, zip.out)
  })
```

Comment: Although that may work, I would prefer to keep the Flow stage as a flow. Nonetheless what I'm trying to achieve is relatively similar.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for ! Following the flowGraph stage i'd need to pass the resultant tuple to another flow which reads the StreamMetaData and converts it to some other value along with some other computation. Would you recommend creating a custom GraphStage with logic?

Comment: I´ve done custom source stages. That requires yo to know well how the stream behaves , i.e. when the sink demands for more elements, otherwise you can experiment strange behaviors. So, I´d avoid building custom stages if Akka provides them.